# Ghost IPADDRESS

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet

I have no clue where to ask this question. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

The network config I have in place is as follows. The address on `eth0` is a static IP:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.99  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether e0:69:95:36:c3:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
```

Now I am running a lot of different stuff on this server, but where my issues seems to be is in zabbix.

Now with the fact that this machine has a static IP address of 192.168.1.99, I can also ssh to the same machine on the IP address 192.168.1.135. I have no clue where this IP address is coming from. I cannot figure out how and why I can SSH to a machine on an IP address that is not physically configured.

I run the following commands on the machine.

```
llamprec@kodi:~$ arp -n | grep 192.168.1.135
llamprec@kodi:~$ echo $HOSTNAME
kodi
```

Running the commands from my local workstation.

```
arp -n | grep 192.168.1.135 I get.
192.168.1.135            ether   e0:69:95:36:c3:6c   C                     eth0
```

If I SSH from my machine to kodi with `ssh 192.168.1.135` when the actual static IP address of the machine is 192.168.1.99, I can still connect.

I have absolutely no idea how this is happening.

Has anyone any idea where to even start looking?

Answer (score 0):

maybe a fixed ip and an attributed one by dhcp...I never had this case
what does an
`ifconfig` give

I did see the first order return but we don't know which order was placed, we just see a result of which we don't know the origin.

excuse my poor english i'm french

Comment: <code>llamprec@kodi:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.99  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether e0:69:95:36:c3:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1</code>

Comment: I am sorry I cannot get the formatting correct

Answer (score 0):

i know it's hard to format the text sometimes, but as far as i understand, your ip is 192.168.1.99 and the other one is just in the arp cache ... to delete it you can go and see
here
https://linux-audit.com/how-to-clear-the-arp-cache-on-linux/

it has the advantage of being in your language.
good continuation!